# How the Url path from file path name to another name in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Fins below the route code.

```
Route::get('clientlayout.main.index','InvoiceTicketController@show');
Route::get('clientlayout.main.mydomains','InvoiceTicketController@set');
```

When I run these routes I'm getting the url as

> http://localhost:8000/clientlayout.main.index and 
>    http://localhost:8000/clientlayout.main.mydomains.

I want my Url to be changed as follows:                                                       http://localhost:8000/index and http://localhost:8000/mydomains.

Suggest me a solution for changing the route to rectify this issue.

Comment: use `Route::get('/index','InvoiceTicketController@show');` and `Route::get('/mydomains','InvoiceTicketController@set');` instead of your routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Route::get('/index','InvoiceTicketController@show');
Route::get('/mydomains','InvoiceTicketController@set');
```

for named routes you can use like this way

```
 Route::get('/index','InvoiceTicketController@show')->name('clientlayout.main.index');
```

for more details follow

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 1):

**You should try the route.**

```
Route::get('/clientlayout/main/index','InvoiceTicketController@show');
Route::get('/clientlayout/main/mydomains','InvoiceTicketController@set');
```

*Url is making*

```
http://localhost:8000/clientlayout/main/index
http://localhost:8000/clientlayout/main/mydomains
```

**Or You Should try**

```
Route::get('/index','InvoiceTicketController@show');
Route::get('/mydomains','InvoiceTicketController@set');
```

*Then Url is making*

```
http://localhost:8000/index
http://localhost:8000/mydomains
```